# When Contact is created

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class AnnualRevenueValidation {

    public static void annualRevenue(List<Account> newAccList) {
        
        for(Account acc : newAccList){
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=3000 && acc.Rating ='Hot'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 3000');
            },
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=6000 && acc.Rating ='Warm'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 6000');
            },,
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=10000 && acc.Rating ='Cold'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 10000');
            },
        }
    }
}
```

getting error ==>Expression cannot be assigned

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/342288/edit) your question to include the exceptions you are getting. Any additional details such as stack traces or log file output will further assist the community in finding your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using '==' in your code snippet instead single '='
Please try the following code :

```
public class AnnualRevenueValidation {

    public static void annualRevenue(List<Account> newAccList) {
        
        for(Account acc : newAccList){
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=500 && acc.Rating =='Hot'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 500');
            }
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=300 && acc.Rating =='Warm'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 300');
            }
            if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=100 && acc.Rating =='Cold'){
                acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 100');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within your conditional code inside the forEach loop on `newAccList` when you are checking the `Rating`.

As your code reads, you are attempting to assign Hot, Warm or Cold to Account Rating directly with a conditional statement which we know is not allowed. This attempt is seen to be using the Assignment Operator. You must use an Equality Operator in this case i.e replacing `=` with `==`. See [Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) for the full list supported in Apex.

```
if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=500 && acc.Rating = 'Hot'){
    acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 500');
}
```

replaced by

```
if(acc.AnnualRevenue  >=500 && acc.Rating == 'Hot'){
    acc.adderror('Annual revenue Should be greater than 500');
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Did you replace all 3 Assignment Operators to Equality Operators?

Comment: Yes i replaced, but validation is not working on account.

Comment: But it solved the exception that your OP was opened for right? You may need to open a new post with additional details on your effort to debug the trigger code.